# HTML Editor for CBuilder/Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder

I need to find basic WYSIWYG HTML editor component for C++Builder 5 to let users to create some simple text that I will paste into existing HTML page template.
Just a simple support to create links, add images, use headers/bold/italic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can drop a TWebBrowser on a form and enable designmode on it, like this:

```
// Delphi code..
(WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'on';
```

After executing the above line, the page will be editable. You can type extra text, delete, etc. If you want to make selections bold or insert images, you're going to have to  add some buttons to program that. The cool thing is that you can do that either from Delphi (or C++ builder in your case) or you can add javascript on the page to edit itself.

The contents of the page can be retrieved from

```
(WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.innerHTML;
```

Remember that (WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2) could be nil.

---

Anyway, I can imagine that there are components around that do all the work for you, which is probably a better route to take than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I was hoping to have a component that already has all the buttons included - someting like a baby Frontpage

Comment: If you've got RADPHP, take a look at the `Embarcadero\RadPHP\3.0\plugins\` folder. You'll find `uHTMLEdit.pas` and `uHTMLEdit.dfm`. It's a one-form HTML editor that doesn't have dependencies other than the standard VCL.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick - I tried this unit, but it won't work with MOST html files: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/39594393/twebbrowser-crashes-with-some-html-files

Comment: "After executing the above line, the page will be editable."
I had to add webBrowser1.Navigate( 'about:blank' ); before that or I would get an exception - presumably because there is no page.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [TRichView](http://trichview.com/) due to its world class support, and deep feature set.  While it is not a true "HTML" editor, it does support the ability to export to HTML, even generating the appropriate CSS styles if necessary.  I use it for handling the email portion of our main product and it works very well.  Internally the storage is either RTF (extended to support images better), or as a proprietary format.  There are plenty of examples of a simple editors which would easily suit your needs.

Comment: I've used TRichView for almost 10 years. It is good, but may be overkill for a simple editor. The one deficiency is it doesn't handle alignment of images yet. We've been working on Sergey for years trying to get him to add it. It's always been ... next version. (Maybe this comment will egg him on).

Answer (score 1):

in C++ Builder, it would be something like this:

(wb is a TCppWebBrowser)

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "mshtml.h"

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "SHDocVw_OCX"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::btnNavigateAndEditClick(TObject *Sender)
{
        wb->Navigate((WideString)"www.google.com");
        while (wb->Busy)
                Application->ProcessMessages();

        if (wb->Document)
        {
                IHTMLDocument2 *html;
                wb->Document->QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>(&html);
                html->put_designMode(L"On");
                html->Release();
        }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::btnInsertImageClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (wb->Document)
    {
          IHTMLDocument2 *html;
          wb->Document->QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>(&html);
          VARIANT var;
          VARIANT_BOOL receive;
          html->execCommand(L"InsertImage",true,var, &receive);
          html->Release();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::btnGetHtmlClick(TObject *Sender)
{
        if (wb->Document)
        {
                IHTMLDocument2 *html;
                wb->Document->QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>(&html);
                IHTMLElement *pElement;
                html->get_body(&pElement);
                pElement->get_parentElement(&pElement);
                wchar_t *tmp;
                pElement->get_outerHTML(&tmp);
                Memo1->Lines->Text = tmp;
                pElement->Release();
                html->Release();
        }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bsalsa.com/

supplies a free set of `EmbeddedWebBrowser` components with an Edit Designer component
that you link to the `EmbeddedBrowser` window to control design mode and have edit control
save to file, insert links, images, etc...

seems to work well!