# How to Convert Simple RichText to HTML tags in Delphi?

Tags: html, delphi, rtf, delphi-2006, richedit

You may say that there are lots of discussions about this in stackOverflow, but most of them are more complicated than what I need and mostly for other languages.

I have a MySQL remote database in which I have a "Help" table with the code for filling the help pages of the dynamic web site that uses this database.

I decided to make a Delphi application to manage that website instead of doing by the web site itself for more speed and security.

I want to put a `TRichEdit` to make that help text and use simple things like alignment, bold, italic and underlined styles. I don't want to use pictures and fonts.

**How to pick that rich styled text and convert it to HTML** to put to my BLOB field in the remote database **and then reconvert to rich text if I want to edit it again**?

Comment: There is a commercial, easy to use RTF to HTML / RTF to XHTML converter library for Delphi called ScroogeXHTML, which can be configured to process only basic font properties. (disclaimer: I am the author of this library)

Comment: And how much is this library?

Comment: You can find it on [`this page`](http://www.habarisoft.com/scroogexhtml_delphi.html) ;-)

Comment: @EASI - it is about 120 euro :)

Comment: @IceCold for indie developers now much less 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying many different solutions which did not gave accurate results, I was inspired by this solution: [Convert RTF to HTML and HTML to RTF](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3096/Convert-RTF-to-HTML-and-HTML-to-RTF.html).

The idea is that `TWebBrowser` control (in design/edit mode) can handle and convert correctly Rich text format when it was pasted from the clipboard.

```
uses SHDocVw, MSHTML;

function ClipboardToHTML(AParent: TWinControl): WideString;
var
  wb: TWebBrowser;

  function WaitDocumentReady: Boolean;
  var
    StartTime: DWORD;
  begin
    StartTime := GetTickCount;
    while wb.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
    begin
      Application.HandleMessage;
      if GetTickCount >= StartTime + 2000 then // time-out of max 2 sec
      begin
        Result := False; // time-out
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
begin
  Result := '';
  wb := TWebBrowser.Create(nil);
  try
    wb.Silent := True;
    wb.Width := 0;
    wb.Height := 0;
    wb.Visible := False;
    TWinControl(wb).Parent := AParent;
    wb.HandleNeeded;
    if wb.HandleAllocated then
    begin
      wb.Navigate('about:blank');
      (wb.Document as IHTMLDocument2).designMode := 'on';
      if WaitDocumentReady then
      begin
        (wb.Document as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('Paste', False, 0);
        Result := (wb.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.innerHTML;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    wb.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.SelectAll;
  RichEdit1.CopyToClipboard;

  ShowMessage(ClipboardToHTML(Self));
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work good. Font sizes are not equivalent.

Comment: it doesnt works on rich text with attachments....

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to generate RTF content using a `TRichEdit`, then you should store the native RTF it generates alongside the converted HTML.  If the only reason you are using `TRichEdit` is so that you can have simple formatting capabilities, then you are probably better off using an HTML edit control that generates native HTML content.

Regardless of which way you go, it is best to store the native format for users to edit the content, and convert it as needed to other formats (instead of converting it both directions).

If you use `TRichEdit`, then you can easily stream the RTF content in and out of the control, although I recommend `TJvRichEdit` over `TRichEdit`:

```
procedure GetRTFData(MS: TMemoryStream; RTF: TRichEdit);
begin
  MS.Clear;
  RTF.Lines.SaveToStream(MS);
  MS.Position := 0;
end;

procedure SetRTFData(MS: TMemoryStream; RTF: TRichEdit);
begin
  MS.Position := 0;
  RTF.StreamFormat := sfRichText;
  RTF.Lines.LoadFromStream(MS);
end;
```

Manually converting RTF to HTML is not an easy task.  There are unicode character considerations, font styles, font codes, paragraph formatting, numbered lists, special HTML characters, and SO much more.  Even though you only need to support simple formatting, users often use other features that cause conversion headaches -- like copying content from MSWord and pasting it into your app with all sort of formatting and font styles.

`JvRichEditToHtml` does a decent job converting RTF to HTML, but we ended up writing our own conversion unit because we do a lot more with RTF than simple formatting.  `JvRichEditToHtml` should easily handle what you've described as long as users don't introduce complex content via a copy/paste, or use the keyboard shortcuts to format the content (e.g., bullets = ctrl+shft+L, indent = ctrl+M, etc.).

There are also several good HTML edit controls for Delphi if you want to bypass the complexities of authoring in RTF and converting to HTML:

[Google Results :: Delphi, HTML, Editor, Component](http://www.google.com/search?q=delphi%20html%20editor%20component)

- [HTML Editor for CBuilder/Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402455/html-editor-for-cbuilder-delphi)
- [WYSIWYG HTML Editor Component for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146116/wysiwyg-html-editor-component-for-delphi)
- [The quest for an HTML editor VCL control](http://delphimisver.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/the-quest-for-an-html-editor-vcl-control/)

[Stack Overflow :: Delphi, HTML, Editor, Component](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi%20html%20editor%20component)

- [Delphi with HTML/CSS interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175937/delphi-with-html-css-interface)
- (and many others!)

We use `TRichView` because of its extensive capabilities.  It can load/create RTF, and export HTML.  It isn't free however.  If you are looking for something free, `TJvRichView` and `JvRichEditToHtml` are good options.

Comment: I struggled with those HTML editors. They are not even half-decent/complete. Even the commercial solutions are sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

that really works good for me.  without TWebBrowser.

but from html to richedit.

hope someone find it useful.

```
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                    //
    //          Formatting Richedit with HTML tags        //
    //                    by Carbonize                    //
    //                                                    //
    //    This is my second Delphi project and another    //
    //    conversion of one of my Visual Basic codes.     //
    //                                                    //
    //    This code goes through a string looking for     //
    //    <xxx> style tags then formats the richedit      //
    //    according to the text in the tag. It does       //
    //    colours, italics, bold, underline, line breaks, //
    //    font face, and font size.                       //
    //                                                    //
    //    I made the original VB version as a way of      //
    //    formatting the help files in one of my programs //
    //    to make them look better and be easier to read. //
    //                                                    //
    //    Please remember I am new to Delphi so some      //
    //    of the code may be sloppy. When handling        //
    //    <Font tags I did it the long way so it could    //
    //    handle tags with spaces between the 'face' or   //
    //    'size' and the actual face/size such as         //
    //    <font name = "Comic Sans MS"> as some people    //
    //    do their HTML this way.                         //
    //                                                    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                    //
    //             Monday, 27th January 2003              //
    //                                                    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls;

    type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    txtHTML: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    rchHTML: TRichEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DisplayText(Tag: string; Buf:string);
    procedure FontTags(Tag: string; Buf:string);
    private
    { Private declarations }
    public
    { Public declarations }
    end;

    var
    Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
            Buf : string;
            Bumf : string;
            tag : string;
    begin
    //Clear the Richedit and set default formatting
    rchHTML.text := '';
    rchHTML.SelAttributes.style := [];
    rchHTML.selattributes.color := clBlack;
    rchHTML.SelAttributes.Name := 'MS Sans Serif';
    rchHTML.SelAttributes.Size := 8;

    //strip all new line commands as it screws the code up.
    Bumf := stringreplace(txtHTML.Text, #13#10, '', [rfReplaceAll]);

    //if there's no '<' then there's no tags so display whole string.
    if pos('<', Bumf) = 0 then
    begin   //but first convert any <> replacement strings.
            Bumf := stringreplace(Bumf, '&lt;', '<', [rfReplaceAll]);
            Bumf := stringreplace(Bumf, '&gt;', '>', [rfReplaceAll]);
            Bumf := stringreplace(Bumf, '&amp;', '&', [rfReplaceAll]);
            rchHTML.SelText := Bumf;
            exit;
    end;

    //else thats display all text before the '<'.
    //But first convert any replacements that are in there.
    Buf := copy(Bumf, 0, pos('<', Bumf) - 1);
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&lt;', '<', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&gt;', '>', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&amp;', '&', [rfReplaceAll]);
    rchHTML.SelText := Buf;

    //then strip all text before the '<'
    delete(Bumf, 1 ,pos('<', Bumf) - 1);

    //If there's no '>' then it's not a tag so just post it all
    If pos('>', Bumf) = 0 then
    begin
            rchHTML.SelText := Bumf;
            exit;
    end;

    //else we need to parse any and all tags and the strings to post
    While length(Bumf) > 0 do
    begin
    //the tag := all text between '<' and '>'
    Tag := copy(Bumf, 2, pos('>', Bumf) - 2);
    //the text we will post is everything after the '>'
    Buf := copy(Bumf, pos('>', Bumf) + 1, length(Bumf) - pos('>', Bumf));
    //Empty Bumf
    Bumf := '';
    //Are there any '<'s in the tag?
    while pos('<', tag) > 0 do
    begin  //if so then post all text before the'<' as it's not part of a tag
            rchhtml.SelText := '<' + copy(Tag, 1, pos('<', Tag) - 1);
            //tag then := all text from the '<'
            Tag := copy(Tag, pos('<', Tag) + 1, length(Tag) - pos('<', Tag));
    End;
    //if there's a '<' in Buf then there may be another Tag
    If pos('<', Buf) > 0 then
    begin   //So we make Bumf := everything after the '<'
            Bumf := copy(Buf, pos('<', Buf), (length(Buf) - pos('<', Buf)) + 1);
            //And buf := everything before it
            Buf := copy(Buf, 1, pos('<', Buf) - 1);
    end;
    //now we pass the tag and the buf text to our text formatting procedure
    DisplayText(Tag, Buf);
    end;

    end;

    procedure TForm1.DisplayText(Tag: string; Buf:string);
    begin
    //There is a problem where if buf = '' the richedit attributes didn't get set
    //so I included this shoddy fix.
    //If you know why this bug happens please let me know.
    If Buf = '' then Buf := #12;

    //in case we want to actually show a tag or the markers used for < and >
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&lt;', '<', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&gt;', '>', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Buf := stringreplace(Buf, '&amp;', '&', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Tag := stringreplace(Tag, '&lt;', '<', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Tag := stringreplace(Tag, '&gt;', '>', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Tag := stringreplace(Tag, '&amp;', '&', [rfReplaceAll]);

    //if it's a font tag then send it to font handling
    If copy(lowercase(Tag), 0, 5) = 'font ' then
    begin
    FontTags(Tag, Buf);
    exit;
    end;

    //go through all known tags, formatting richedit as appropriate
    if lowercase(Tag) = 'red' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clRed
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'black' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'blue' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'cyan' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clAqua
    else if ((lowercase(Tag) = 'gray') or (lowercase(Tag) = 'grey')) then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clGray
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'green' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'pink' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clFuchsia
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'purple' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clPurple
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'yellow' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Color := clYellow
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'b' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style + [fsBold]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = '/b' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style - [fsBold]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'i' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style + [fsItalic]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = '/i' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style - [fsItalic]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'u' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style + [fsUnderline]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = '/u' then
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style := rchHTML.SelAttributes.Style - [fsUnderline]
    else if lowercase(Tag) = 'br' then
            Buf := #13#10 + Buf        
    //If it's an unknown tag then display the tag
    else Buf := '<' + Tag + '>' + Buf;

    //Now we've set the attributes we can display the text.
    rchHTML.SelText := Buf;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FontTags(Tag: string; Buf:string);
    var
            a: integer;
            tag2: String;
    begin
    //we know it's a font tag so strip the 'font '
    Delete(Tag, 1, 5);

    //lets see if the want to set the font face
    If pos('face', lowercase(Tag)) > 0 then
    begin   //get the position of 'face'
            a := pos('face', lowercase(Tag));
            //set our temporary string to := all text from 'face' to the end.
            tag2 := copy(Tag, a, length(Tag) - (a - 1));
            //Then get position of the opening".
            a := pos('"', Tag2) + 1;
            //set our temporary string to := all text from " + 1 to the end.
            Tag2 := copy(Tag2, a, length(Tag2) - (a - 1));
            //Then locate the closing "
            a := pos('"', Tag2) - 1;
            //then make tag2 = the text between " and "
            Tag2 := copy(Tag2, 1, a);
            //Now set the font name to the chosen one.
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Name := Tag2;
    end;

    //Now check if they want to set the fonts size.
    If pos('size', lowercase(Tag)) > 0 then
    begin   //get the position of 'size'
            a := pos('size', lowercase(Tag));
            //Make temporary string := all text from 'size' to end of the tag
            tag2 := copy(Tag, a, length(Tag) - (a - 1));
            //get position of opening "
            a := pos('"', Tag2) + 1;
            //make tag2 := all text from " + 1 to the end.
            Tag2 := copy(Tag2, a, length(Tag2) - (a - 1));
            //get position of the closing "
            a := pos('"', Tag2) - 1;
            //make tag2 := text between " and "
            Tag2 := copy(Tag2, 1, a);
            //set the fonts size
            rchHTML.SelAttributes.Size := strtoint(Tag2);
    end;

    //Now we've formatted we can display the text.
    rchHTML.seltext := Buf;

    end;

    end.
```

Comment: Website is down. Do you still have the code?

Comment: updated. added code. just add a richedit, memo and a button

Comment: Thanks but this converts HTML to RichEdit. I wouldn't use this because HTML includes lots of CSS nowadays.