# RTF Text on TRichEdit - Delphi 2010

Tags: html, delphi, rtf, delphi-2010

Good morning all.

I have a question about handle of TRichEdit.

In a TRichEdit I have a text with several riched formats (Bold, Italic, Underline) like this:

[image: RTF Text]

Can I have the possibility of know the style of each character in the Edit, for instance, the first 's' has no format, the first 'r' has a bold format, the second 'a' has italic format, and the fourth 'a' has underline format?

The purpose of this question is for convert this text to HTML tags. I tried many functions on Internet and no one works for me.

I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Have you tried opening your .rtf file in notepad and examining it that way?

Comment: You might also want to try saving the rtf as html and seeing what that outputs

Comment: It will be very slow if you operate character by character. But yes you can iterate over each character with `SelStart` and `SelLength`. Then you read `SelAttributes` IIRC.

Comment: @David - I did that once many years ago - it was a very painful process

Comment: Is it your intention to convert the contents of a rich edit to HTML? Or to convert rich text format to HTML? Because if it's the latter, you shouldn't bother using a rich edit control at all, but read the raw RTF format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954946/how-to-convert-simple-richtext-to-html-tags-in-delphi -> https://www.habarisoft.com/scroogexhtml_delphi.html